# How to add custom location is Save As dialog box?

Tags: windows-xp, save-as

I want to add a custom folder location in "Save As" and "Save" dialog box. Currently it shows "My Computer" , "Desktop" , "My Documents" and "My Recent Documents" option on the LHS of the dialog box. I want to add a custom location "C:\Test" there.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To change the default XP one you need to use the [TweakUI powertoy](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsxp/Downloads/powertoys/Xppowertoys.mspx).

[image]

However, some applications implement this dialog in different ways.

Microsoft Office 2003 for example uses its own version of the Save dialog and has an `Add to "My Places"` option on the tools menu.

[image]

Comment: This TweakUI settings is not well known but damn useful. I use it to put favorites in `Save as...` dialogs